# Can a signal interrupt a 64bit int memory write on aarch64?

Tags: kernel, signals

I need to save a changing message sequence number at speed in a linux C program running on aarch64, because the program may be terminated by a signal and will have to be restarted.

For context, these are kernel printk message sequence numbers. But this is a user space program.

I am currently planning to do this using shared memory. I am assuming an occasional maximum of low hundreds of messages per second, so I don’t want to repeatedly write and sync a file.

My question is this: will a 64bit int memory write ever be interrupted by a signal in a way which leaves the memory location invalid? Equivalently, is the write always atomic with respect to signals?

If I have to, I will use more than one location and surround the writes with semaphore updates, to show the validity of each location.

UPDATE: I have just noticed RSEQ restartable sequences, which might be a clean way to avoid semaphores.

Your advice is sought.